# Inner join y left Join en Access

Tags: ms-access

Tengo un inconveniente con una consulta en **access**, deseo incluir un `join` y un `left`  y el error que aparece al momento de guardar la consulta del `access` me da el siguente **error**:

> "Expresion Join no se admite"

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT 
doc.c_numeoc AS "N° OC",
n_totimp AS Precio,
doc.c_desprd AS Descripcion_Equipo,
e.c_nserie AS Serie_Equipo,
c_cfabri AS Marca_Caja,
c_cmodel AS Modelo_Caja,
c_canofab AS Año_Fab_Caja,
c_mcamaq AS Marca_Maquina,
c_cmodel AS Modelo_Maquina,
c_codsit AS Estado_Contable,
c_codsitalm AS Estado_Almacen
 FROM
   (((invequipo e
   INNER JOIN invmae i ON e.c_codprd=i.IN_CODI)
   LEFT JOIN detaoc doc ON e.c_nserie = doc.c_nroserie)
   INNER JOIN cabeoc coc ON coc.c_numeoc=doc.c_numeoc)
WHERE
      e.c_codsit<>'T'
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta que nunca haces el `FROM` a la primer tabla de ahí en adelante debes de ir usando los `INNER JOIN`.

La consulta quedaria así:

```
SELECT 
doc.c_numeoc AS "N° OC",
n_totimp AS Precio,
doc.c_desprd AS Descripcion_Equipo,
e.c_nserie AS Serie_Equipo,
c_cfabri AS Marca_Caja,
c_cmodel AS Modelo_Caja,
c_canofab AS Año_Fab_Caja,
c_mcamaq AS Marca_Maquina,
c_cmodel AS Modelo_Maquina,
c_codsit AS Estado_Contable,
c_codsitalm AS Estado_Almacen
 FROM 
  ((invequipo e
  INNER JOIN invmae i 
  ON e.c_codprd=i.IN_CODI)
  LEFT JOIN detaoc doc 
 ON e.c_nserie = doc.c_nroserie)
  INNER JOIN cabeoc coc ON coc.c_numeoc=doc.c_numeoc;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero si se esta haciendo el llamado  FROM
   (((**invequipo** e INNER JOIN invmae i ON e.c_codprd=i.IN_CODI)
   LEFT JOIN detaoc doc ON e.c_nserie = doc.c_nroserie)
   INNER JOIN cabeoc coc ON coc.c_numeoc=doc.c_numeoc), le coloco los parentesis adelante, porque segun estructura en el access se trabaja de esa forma

Comment: Puedes compartime si usaste alguna fuente para hacer la consulta

Comment: No utilice ninguna fuente, solo investigando encontre que la forma para declarar los inner join son con los parentesis, y te doy una apreciacion mas, cuando quito el inner join ultimo, la consulta funciona correctamente

Comment: Ya has probado poniendole parentesis al where tambien

Comment: Si , pero sale el mismo error

Comment: Edite la respuesta mira si te funciona así

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76810/discussion-between-raul-cacacho-and-vanesa-claros).